# Product Developer vs Product Designer. What's the difference?

Tags: design, product-design, roles

I've notice that more and more people who used to call themselves Product Designer or Product Developer.

Most of the time maybe they work on the same things. I'm struggling to find any good articles on this and I'm wondering if somebody could help to clearly define the real difference between these two roles.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[image: An image morphing from a sketch to a real room]

From dictionary.com:

> Design:  To prepare the preliminary sketch or the plans for (a work to be executed), especially to plan the form and structure of.
>
> Develop: To cause to grow or expand.

Designers make the plans, developers execute them.

The output of (UX/Software) designers *is not* a working system, but rather a blueprint for it.

The output of software developers *is* a working system.

By way of analogy, **architects** design, **builders** develop.

UX and software designers don't build the product - developers do.

Note that sometimes the design *is* the product, like most of the output of graphic designers. But a system needs someone to build it.